# how to verify the downloaded excel content from chrome browser using selenium and handling protected view of downloaded excel file

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I am able to downloaded Excel workbooks using java-selenium.

[image]

The downloaded Excel files are in protected view. How can I disable the protected view using java-selenium

[image]

Comment: You can't because this is a local trust center setting.  Please read [What is Protected View?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653) and especially [I want to change my Protected View settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653#bm5).

Comment: Any alternate solutions to automate, to open the downloaded excel file from chrome browser and click on "Enable Editing" in downloaded excel file